# cartesian coordinates for points along an arc on the side of a cylinder.

Tags: trigonometry

I am a machinist by trade tasked with creating a program for interpolating an arc along the side of a cylinder. It needs to be parametric by nature since the final result will be a need to be adaptable to any an arc of any degree or length and the cylinder would also have to be parametric. I can iterate across the degrees of the arc but I need to be able to convert the next point into Cartesian coordinates XYZ and I'm having difficulty finding a good starting point for the formulas. I'm no stranger to trigonometry, but in the case of having two different phases/thetas I can't fully get a good grip. I'm more or less looking for some good pointers to start on, unless you find it an interesting challenge you wish to tackle yourself!

Comment: I can see why there is one "theta" -- distance around the base of the cylinder can be measured by an angle. But where does the second "theta" come from when you have "two different phases/thetas"?

Comment: For reasons I don't really understand, I don't think stackexchange will let you post a picture here until you have more reputation points. But you can edit a link to a picture of the problem (if you have one) into your question, and that would enable one of us to include the picture itself. Perhaps a picture would help.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, there is two theta because I'm mapping point to point first the arc with has its own theta to iterate then it has to be mapped to the side of the cylinder which is a seperate theta.

Comment: Got it. The arc is circular too. What you figured out in the comment under the answer is a good way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the vertical cylinder has radius $1$ and you want to join the point $(1,0,0)$ to the point $(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, h)$. You can do that with either of the curves
$$
t \mapsto ( 1 - t(1 - \cos \theta), t \sin \theta, th)
$$
and
$$
t \mapsto ( \cos t\theta,   \sin t\theta, th).
$$
Each maps the unit interval $[0,1]$ to a curve that wraps around the cylinder joining those to points.

One of them is the shortest path - I think the second - but I haven't checked.

You can translate, rotate and scale any two points on any cylinder to match this picture.

If $\theta > \pi$ you will want to wrap the other way.

Comment: This looks close to what I'm looking for. After posting this I've given the problem considerable  thought and I realized that the problem is actually simpler than I originally thought. I just have to first iterate a point on the arc, then I have to map it to the cylinder as a second operation. Seems simple now, I think I was originally obsessing over a general formula that would be able to map the points in a single operation/formula.